# Java: MDB and Spring's SingletonBeanFactoryLocator

Tags: java, spring, ejb

In a code base that I've inherited, there's an `MDB` which is calling `SingletonBeanFactoryLocator().getIntance().useBean()` to get a factory reference in its `ejbCreate()`, and then getting a specific bean from this factory and storing it as an `MDB` instance variable. (The factory is of type '`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`').

**The confusing part is:** after that bean is obtained, it's calling '`release()`' on this factory reference in that same `ejbCreate()`.

Now, this `MDB` is pooled with poolsize '`x`' and what I've observed is, beans defined in the `context xml` are getting created '`x`' number of times. So my guess is, every time the '`ejbCreate()`' executes, it's creating a context and its beans afresh.

I checked Spring doc for '`release()` above which says:

```
In an EJB usage scenario this would normally be called from `ejbRemove()` and `ejbPassivate()`.
```

So here're my questions:

1) is it really creating a new context and new beans `everytime ejbCreate()` is called?

2) if yes, what happens to the context/beans created in the previous call (e.g. if the beans are singleton themselves, will they be *destroyed*)?

3) is this the right way to use `SingletonBeanFactoryLocator` (possibly for thread safety issues) in the context above?

4) if not, what *is* the right way to use it?

EDIT: one possibility I can think of is to make the concerned beans `prototype` to make each MDB instance thread-safe, so there's no need to release and recreate the context. Awaiting other comments/suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Nothing happens. The same objects will still be in the same MDBs. The MDB doesn't care and Spring is out of the picture at this point.
3. That really depends on the use circumstances. If you just use Spring to assemble objects and every MDBs should have it's own instances then the answer is yes.
4. Depending on the use case `SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor` may or may not be a better alternative.
5. Prototype can be tricky. You have to understand your beans and the consequences well to make it do what you expect. That's why it's generally best to make spring beans stateless.

**Update:**
There is actually a race condition. If the container decides to run the `ejbCreate()` of two MDBs in parallel then they both will end up sharing the same application context.

**Update 2:**
I could not find a section that explicitly allows EJB creating through parallel threads but I could also not find a section that explicitly forbids it.

Given the following sections from the spec I assume it would be in the spirit of the spec to do it.

---

### 2.4.2 Message-Driven Objects

A typical EJB container provides a scalable runtime environment to execute a large number of mes- sage-driven objects concurrently.

## 5.2 Goals

A further goal of the message-driven bean model is to allow for the concurrent processing of a stream of messages by means of container-provided pooling of message-driven bean instances.

## 5.4 Protocol Between a Message-Driven Bean Instance and its Container

It is the container’s responsibility to ensure that the message-driven bean comes into existence when the container is started up and that instances of the bean are ready to receive an asynchronous message delivery before the delivery of messages is started.

### 5.4.11 Concurrency of Message Processing

A container allows many instances of a message-driven bean class to be executing concurrently, thus allowing for the concurrent processing of a stream of messages. No guarantees are made as to the exact order in which messages are delivered to the instances of the message-driven bean class, although the container should attempt to deliver messages in order when it does not impair the concurrency of mes- sage processing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does the spec allow a server to create ejb's through parallel threads? Could you pl. give any reference for the update in your answer?

Comment: Thanks for the ref. Assuming that there could be a race condition, one possibility would be to make the beanFactory static, and load it in a static block so there's no racing. After that, in ejbCreate(), it will keep on asking for the concerned beans, and if prototype beans are suitable here, then we don't need to close and recreate the context for every ejbCreate.

Comment: You can achieve the same thing by not making the beanFactory static and closing it in `@PreDestory` instead of `@PostConstruct`  methods. This has several advantages like the context gets destroyed once all beans are undeployed.